# OpenSSH import configuration from external files

Tags: configuration, openssh

I've been searching around with no luck, so I'm just asking to make sure.

Is it possible to import an external config file? Example with     ~/.ss/config file :

```
Hosts * 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_servicekey

Include ~/.sshconfig.local
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [no such include feature documented](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5) (and presumably a similar case for portable OpenSSH). Since OpenSSH has had issues with undocumented parameters (the recent `UseRoaming` thing), a quick peek around the source tree, in particular the `readconf.c` file, does not show anything obvious for includes. So, you'll probably have to find some other way to effect an include (e.g. `cd ~/.ssh && cat fooconf localconf > config` or as complicated as you want to make it).

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in current upstrem `openssh` version. But I worked on the patch that would provide this functionality for both client and server.

It is currently available for Fedora from [copr repository](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/jjelen/openssh-include/). The patches are tracked in upstream bugzilla as bugs [#1585](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1585) and [#2468](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2468) and I would be glad for some feedback and testing.

**Update:** The bug [#1585](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1585) was updated but openssh developer, so we can expect some progress in the close future.